# Clear Java Hashtable on rehash?

Tags: java, hashtable

I'm trying to implement `java.util.Hashtable` into my project, however I'm not sure if it can support the functionality I'm looking for.

I'm looking to be able to use `java.util.Hashtable` but on rehash I don't want to copy the data from the original hashtable to the new larger hashtable.

Is there a way to do this with `java.util.Hashtable`?

(Basically I need it to store some values I don't want to recalculate. As the application runs the original values I'm storing will be needed less and less so for performance it's better just to get rid of them and start again with the new, more needed values. The best place to do this would be when rehashing as I could just remove the copy step from the typical rehash process.)

Comment: Why would you want this?  What would be the point of creating a larger, empty, hashtable?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Basically I need it to store some values I don't want to recalculate. As the application runs the original values I'm storing will be needed less and less so for performance it's better just to get rid of them and start again with the new, more needed values.

The best place to do this would be when rehashing as I could just remove the copy step from the typical rehash process.

Comment: Have you thought about using a cache, something like Guava Cache https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/CachesExplained

Comment: @user11406: It is better to edit such clarifications into the question, as not everyone is going to read through all comments. I have done that for you this time.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use [`Hashtable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html). It's a legacy leftover from JDK 1.0, which is unnecessarily syncronized in various points.

Instead, you can use [`HashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html). It doesn't offer an explicit rehash method, but it will rehash itself automagically when it gets too loaded. You can control how often this will happen by initializing the `loadFactor` in the [appropriate constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#HashMap-int-float-). With a sufficiently large `loadFactor`, this rehashing will never happen.

Comment: While I believe this is rather informative I honestly can't see how it's the answer to the question rather than something to bring up in the comments.

Comment: Erm, perhaps OP is relying on the cache being synchronized? Caches are often accessed (and updated) concurrently.

Answer (score 1):

The `clear()` method is used to clear the hashtable. Use `hashTable.clear();` to clear your hashtable on refresh.

Source : [TutorialsPoint](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/hashtable_clear.htm)

Comment: For performance reasons I don't want to do it like that. For this to work I would need to rehash, which involves copying all the data to a larger hashtable just to delete all the copied data. I just want to not copy the data over.

Answer (score 1):

> Basically I need it to store some values I don't want to recalculate. As the application runs the original values I'm storing will be needed less and less so for performance it's better just to get rid of them and start again with the new, more needed values.

So you want to have a cache with a least-recently-added eviction policy. The easiest implementation is as follows:

```
class LRACache<K, V> extends LinkedHashMap<K, V> {
    @Override
    protected boolean removeEldestEntry(java.util.Map.Entry<K, V> eldest) {
        return size() > 100; 
    }
}
```

By invoking a different constructor of LinkedHashMap, you can also evict the least-recently-used (i.e. requested) element instead.

Test code:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        LRACache<Integer, Integer> cache = new LRACache<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
            cache.put(i, i);
        }
        if (cache.containsKey(1)) {
            throw new AssertionError();
        }
        if (!cache.containsKey(100)) {
            throw new AssertionError();
        }
        System.out.println(cache);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [`LinkedHashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html). It is a hashmap that allows you to iterate it by the order you have entered the values to the hash map.

It can be subclassed, and the `removedEldestEntry()` overridden, to set a policy whereby upon inserting a new entry, the eldest one will be deleted. You can do this if the list has reached a certain size, or if the eldest entry has some time field you can test, etc.

This will enable you to get rid of old entries if you see fit, without the toll of copying new entries over to a new map. Or you can use the order iterator to skip old entries and copy only new ones to a new empty hash map if you see fit.